# How to pass current value of array either as a varaible or a parameter to rest dataset to dynamically create rest api endpoints in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I  have a parent and child pipeline.

My task is to call the rest API endpoints such as:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=INCOME_STATEMENT&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo
and store the data in Parquet format in adls. For every symbol such as "IBM," I need to modify the API URL for BALANCE_SHEET, and CASH_FLOW and fetch data and store it in respective data folders such as balance sheet, and cash flow.

My current pipelines:
My parent pipeline has a lookup activity for each activity
where the lookup activity fetches symbols from a csv file. The FOR each iterates and executes a child pipeline which has another for each activity within which there is a dataflow. I need help in iterating the child pipeline over an array such as = ["BALANCE_SHEET", "CASH_FLOW", "INCOME_STATEMENT"].

I tried creating a parameter as an array type and set for each activity to iterate over the array however , when I try to pass the current value to the rest dataset, it passes the entire array and I cannot reference the current item to modify the string to dynamically place the parquet files. ex: "BALANCE_SHEET" to "balance sheet"

I Tried creating an array variable but cannot reference it in parametrized datasets.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dataset parameters to achieve your requirement.

Create string type parameter `symbol` in the source dataset(REST) and use it in the Relative URL of the dataset.

[image]

```
&symbol=@{dataset().symbol}&apikey=demo
```

[image]

Similarly, create a parameter and use it in the folder name of the parquet dataset as well.

[image]

Use both datasets as source and sink of the dataflow. Inside the inner ForEach, provide the necessary values for the parameters in the dataflow activity like below.

[image]

Here, for folder name, use the expression `@toLower(replace(item(),'_',''))`.

This will iterate through the provided array `["BALANCE_SHEET", "CASH_FLOW", "INCOME_STATEMENT"]` and the parameters will build the necessary URLs and folders dynamically.

Comment: Hi thank you for getting back but can I use one rest dataset? . The inner for each iterates over a variable of array type. I need to call for each symbol , I need Api to change its function to "BALANCE_SHEET" and so on . it has to also store in respective directories I have in place ex: balancesheet , cashflow.
I need to pass the array parameter to rest dataset to create three API URLs dynamically. Your solution only includes symbol.

Comment: In each iteration, it will pass the symbol from array to REST dataset and it will build the respective URL dynamically and also the folder will be created dynamically in each iteration.

Comment: I'm sorry this hasn't answered my question. But thank you

Comment: I need a parametrized Rest dataset. in the URL I need to pass function =BALANCE_SHEET, CASH_FLOW, INCOME_STATEMENT dynamically 

ex: 
query?function=INCOME_STATEMENT&symbol=IBM


I tried passing it as an array in the dynamic URL section but then the whole array is referenced which breaks the URL. Also, I do understand that parameters cannot change during the pipeline run which makes it hard to reference because the rest datasets take in only parameters. Hope this made it clear

Comment: Give the Base URL in REST resource as `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?` and the relative URL use the parameter for the required function like this `function=@{dataset().symbol}&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo`. This will work for you.

Comment: It did not work. The function should be BALANCE_SHEET for balancesheetfolder , and so on. this does not solve my issue. symbol = "IBM"  and function in the URL is "BALANCE_SHEET" CALL URL and send it to balancesheet folder

Comment: The same pipeline design will iterate through the array `["BALANCE_SHEET", "CASH_FLOW", "INCOME_STATEMENT"]` and with the dataset parameter in relative URL, pass the `@item` to that parameter in the copy activity source and do the same for target dataset. pass the `@toLower(replace(item(),'_',''))` expression to that as shown in above image. You just need to change the URL as said in the previous comment. It will change the URL dynamically and it will copy each one to its respective folder dynamically. if it doesn't work provide the error/blockers that it is giving?

Comment: Hi  Rakesh i have two for each activity , the parent pipeline has a for each activity which iterates over symbols like "IBM" , and "MMM" . The child pipeline needs to receive this parameter and for each symbol I need three dynamic URLs  and also need to place those API responses in respective folders. The issue I'm facing is I can't pass the array values and reference it. Also after trying I just the the first function working = "BALANCE_SHEET" . However it did not work for other functions as the dataset parameter cannot change as a rule in adf. Only variables can change

Comment: I have currently, one rest dataset with two parameters namely, ticker and datacategory. both these are of type string. I have one common sink with same parameters and type. Now I have parent pipeline iterate over each symbol , this symbol is passed down as pipelineparameter to child pipeline. The child pipeline has only one for each activity which iterates over an variable of type array. This array is the nameso of function. After running this , the rest dataset doesn't call URL  for functions "CASHFLOW" & "INCOME_STATEMENT" . Only "BALANCE_SHEET" works. not sure why. Is this correct?

Comment: Can you provide your child pipeline JSON once?

Comment: Also all three url return different number of columns and column names. Can i make it dynamic or is the mapping taken care of internally?

Comment: As you are copying the files to different locations and generating a target file for every iteration, that won't be an issue I think. The Dataflow will dynamically copy it to the targets. But, make sure the schema in the dataset in clear. If there is any schema imported in the dataset, the dataflow will apply the same schema for every iteration.

Comment: Hi Rakesh , i believe that could be an issue , i import projection and reset schema. Is there a way to contact you ? I'm using a dataflow activity to parse json  response using flatten activity. Does that mean i need separate dataflows? I'm confused about this. Each API response gives back different columns so do i need to manually map it in flatten activity or does it happen dynamically because the URL has body and headers as part of the return response

Comment: when I trigger the pipeline based on your solution , it succeeds however the files are same in all three folders with same column names. Not sure why this is happening

Comment: you cannot use same dataflow if you want to flatten or parse different files in the dataflow. As the schema changes the flatten or parse settings should also change. Use 3 dataflows in the witch case in ForEach, so that you can call required dataflow for every iteration. That could be possible solution but its better to flatten or parse with any programming language code rather than ADF dataflow to avoid this complex approach.

Comment: thank you i guess I wasn't aware of that. I'll use three different dataflows